# MongoDB find count of all entries in child array by key

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection in my MongoDB database which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "0123456789",
  "merchants": {
    "13142": {
      "Deeplink1": "http://xx.tld",
      "ProgramID": 13142,
      "Price": 24.9,
      "EAN": "0123456789",
      "Shipping": 0.0,
      "CF_Farbe": "schwarz",
      "CF_Geschlecht": "men",
      "CF_Größe": "L",
      "CF_ImgUrl2": "http://img.tld",
      "CF_Stamm-Artikelnummer": "329830",
      "CF_verfügbare Größen": "S, L"
    }
  }
}
```

These are merchant information for products. The `_id` is the product code, "merchants" is an array with the merchant id as key.

Now I need to count of all entries of a merchant with a specific merchant id ("13142" for example). How can I perform it (with the php MongoClient class)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Side note: it's considered not a good practice to have dynamic keys as fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.collenctionName.find({'merchants.13142':{$exists:true}}).count()` this will give you your result in `mongodb` console, please convert it according to `php` .. i am in `.net` so cann't told you the php code..

Use `'.'` operator to find `inner level` property.. like here in answer i used `'merchants.13142'`